# How to customize bibliography style and citations?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a problem customizing my bibliography format, I need the citation to be in author/year format which is now displaying correctly, however I need to put square brackets around each citation and a comma in between the author/year.

My citation now is showing as:

**Author 1991**

Instead I need it to be as follows:

**[Author, 1991]**

Also in the bibliography page where it shows all the references in the last page, currently it is displaying as follows:

**Author (1991)."XX publication". XX publisher, pp. X–X**

But I need it to show in two lines adding the citation abbreviation in the first line then the reference in the second, also I need to add the year in the end after the publisher and with no parenthesis. The references must be ordered alphabetically by author name which is showing correctly now. The required format is as follows:

**[Author, 1991]**

**Author."XX publication". XX publisher, 1991, pp. X–X**

Here is what I am using currently:

```
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
```

and for the bibliography page:

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=References, resetnumbers=true]
```

here is a sample from my "example.bib" file:

```
@article{11,
    author = {Author},
    title = {XXX},
    journal = {IEEE},
    year = {1991}
}
```

And here is an example of my citation:

```
\cite{11}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's not recommended to use `bibtex` as the backend for `biblatex`. Remove that and compile using `biber` instead. The citation command for the name and date in brackets is `\parencite` not `\cite`. For the first two questions, use the following: `\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{[}{]}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} ` The last question is more complex to achieve, and is a very non-standard looking format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `biblatex-ext` styles can do everything that you need. As I mentioned in the comment, you should remove `backend=bibtex` from your loading options for `biblatex` and compile with `biber` instead.

To achieve the `[Author, Year]` format in citations you have two options. You can use the `\autocite` command, or you can use the `\parencite` command. Using `\autocite` has an advantage if you may need to use very different citation styles across different versions of a document, since it will adapt to other styles automatically. If you only use an author-year style then using `\parencite` / `\textcite` (which yields Author (Year) format) is also fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=ext-authoryear,
            bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
            introcite=plain,articlein=false,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\par}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{bertram} % \parencite also works here
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1 for `biblatex-ext` ;-). Just a few observations. Instead of `[` and `]` I usually prefer `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibclosebracket`, since the latter interact with the parentheses/bracket tracker: `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}`. I'd probably add `sorting=nyt,` to get a more author-year sorting. To drop the parentheses around the year for `@article`s, you don't need to redefine `issue+date`, just say `\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}`. Lastly, I usually prefer `\autocite` with an appropriate `autocite` option over `\parencite`.

Comment: This is perfect! just one more thing if it is possible to make the first line (the author year in brackets part) in the references bold.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, (as usual) for the super helpful comments. So many field formats to keep track of :). As someone who only ever will require author/year citations I must confess to not being an `\autocite` user since it serves no useful purpose for me.

Comment: @s.ali Please see the updated answer which also incorporates moewe's (the author of `biblatex-ext` and one of the `biblatex` maintainers) comments.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I have one problem, that some entries are printed on two pages (meaning the title is printed at the very end of a page and description at the next page), how can I prevent that and get Latex to make a pagebreak before printing the entry?

Comment: @s.ali See [biblatex: No pagebreak in bibliography entry](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/43260)

Comment: @AlanMunn this did not work for me \patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{}. I am also unable to edit the bbl file since I am working on Overleaf.

Comment: @s.ali What does "does not work" mean? You still get breaking lines or you get an error?

Comment: No it is still breaking lines.

Comment: @s.ali Did you delete all your cached files and recompile?