# Custom .bib file (fields, data types) with different styling (bibliography style)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, templates, automation, bibliographystyle

I have wanted to start quite an ambitious project, namely a custom resume template that can easily be adapted. I want to automate the following:

[image: example_resume]

As such, I thought it would be nice to have a custom `.bib` file e.g. `activities.bib`:

```
@work{bakery_zeist,
    title = {Baker},
    startdate = {06/2022},
    enddate = {08/2024},
    place = {Zeist, Utrecht},
    language = {Dutch}
}

@work{distribution_aalsmeer,
    title = {Distribution Manager},
    company = {Bloemenveiling},
    startdate = {08/2022},
    place = {Aalsmeer},
    language = {Dutch},
    country = {The Netherlands},
    description = {Riding around trucks}
}

@work{coathanger_berlin,
    title = {Cloakroam Employee},
    startdate = {05/2015},
    enddate = {07/2015},
    place = {Berlin},
    language = {English},
    country = {Germany},
    description = {Riding around trucks}
}

@education{
    degree = {M.Sc.},
    school = {Delft University of Technology},
    grade = {7.0},
    place = {Delft, Zuid-Holland},
    startdate = {04/2020},
}
```

where I can add all the activities that might need to go into a resume, inspired by [this post on Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175776/how-can-i-create-entirely-new-data-types-with-biblatex-biber/175896#175896). I was thinking that to make this work I would define a custom bibliography style inspired by [this post on Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564333/how-to-customize-bibliography-style-and-citations). Finally, I want to create my custom document type `resume.cls` (which correctly handles the `activities.bib` file as well as all other commands I want to define), as well as several `<resume-style-name>.sty` files (e.g. one colorful with icons, one plain with two columns, one with sans-serif fonts, etc.). A bare-bones implementation would hopefully look something like this:

```
\documentclass{resume}  % Custom resume class I want to make
\usepackage{plain_twocolumn}  % (One of the) custom resume style classes I want to make

\begin{document}

% Here set the name of the section title
\section{Experience}

% Here include the relevant experiences
\includehere{bakery_zeist, distribution_aalsmeer}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that I am not really well-versed in LaTex, so that brings me to my question:

- Is this approach smart, i.e. using a .bib file and defining a custom bibliography style, or does this have major limitations/is there an easier way to accomplish this?
- Are there any tutorials/tips/tricks templates I could follow to make this work?

Any tips, MWEs, or advice on how to approach the project would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: You need to learn LaTeX first. You then need to learn Biber and Biblatex well enough to not only define a bibliography style, but to define custom fields and a custom source mapping. That's a major undertaking and would be even for somebody experienced. I'd look at the L3 programming layer first. Perhaps something like property lists would be more straightforward to implement.

Comment: Maybe you want to look into [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) and, if you insist on abusing BibTeX, section 10 of the ConTeXt [publications manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf) – this is for ConTeXt, not LaTeX, but might give some hints. [biblatex-cv](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-cv) might be of interest as well

Comment: The disadvantage of `.bib` files is that you always have to involve a second program like Biber or BibTeX and that you usually have a separate `.bib` file (which may or may not be a disadvantage for your specific use case). The main use of BibTeX and Biber in LaTeX is their sorting capability. In a CV though the sorting should generally be very easy or may even be done by hand so that you can probably get away with using just LaTeX-side solutions.

Comment: Thanks guys, these are all great suggestions! I'll definitely check out `biblatex-cv`, it seems  like they indeed have some of the capabilities I'm after. Finally, I would like to add that I in no way insist on using BibTeX, I just thought that would be the easiest way to accomplish what I'm after, namely creating a separate file with all my experiences/education, and then selectively loading each entry (with a custom formatting). But it seems like that's a too daunting task at the moment and not something that will outcompete manual labor in the short term. But thanks again!

Comment: I've just written a couple of CVs for job applications and I found that for each of the applications I would highlight a different thing in the job description, so I'm wondering how useful this approach with the external `.bib` file is anyway if significant portions of the text are tweaked. Sure the hard data (start end date) stays the same, but that you can probably just copy-paste from another CV.